# How can I get the that specific html tag that have a href javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of lines that gets generated depending on user that looks like this:

```
<div class"Item">
<a href="javascript:GetDocumentInfo('${Url}', this);">Test 1</a>
</div>
<div class"Item">
<a href="javascript:GetDocumentInfo('${Url}', this);">Test 2</a>
</div>
<div class"Item">
<a href="javascript:GetDocumentInfo('${Url}', this);">Test 3</a>
</div>
<div class"Item">
<a href="javascript:GetDocumentInfo('${Url}', this);">Test 4</a>
</div>
```

the javascript looks like this:

```
function GetDocumentInfo(url,e) {      
     $('.container').load(url + " .main");
    alert(e.ClassName);
}
```

This is what I have tried above, I want to change color on that specific `a` tag that gets clicked by the user.
So basicly What I have tried is to try to get it with the javascript and then try to play with but `e.ClassName` is null.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Why using href attribute? Why not onclick, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/nEU5t/? Why this question is tagged with jQuery?

Comment: @A.Wolff I updated the function I added it beacuse I had a code in it with jQuery

Comment: Ok so jQuery tag makes more sense now ;) But you should then bind click event using jQuery, would make it really more simple anyway. BTW, it should be `<div class="Item">`

Comment: also `e.className` has lower case `c` i guess

Comment: If I want to use pure jquery I think that I need to alot of changes, beacuse im using jQuery template to display data info right now the parameter url is hardcoded on this example in my code it has ${Url}. But I will take a look at it, I could add a attrib or something to get the url with jQuery

Comment: In jQuery, it's for sure more readable: http://jsfiddle.net/nEU5t/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff hmm the page reloads on click now :S when I tried your jsfiddle

Comment: @Obsivus it doesn't for me on jsFiddle. If it does on your site, then you are doing something wrong

Answer (score -2):

The following script will help?

```
function getDocumentInfo(url,that){
    $(that).css('color','red');
}
```

Comment: Changed the variable name. The author used the variable `e` so I didn't changed that earlier.

Comment: Oh yes. That should be onclik="javascript:GetDocumentInfo('http://test.com', this);" href="#"